# fastlane FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD is not working?

Tags: fastlane

i am using fastlane to automate uploading build to app store, after the 2FA became mandatory, am trying to use FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD in env file to overcome 2FA however i try , i could not overcome 2FA it keeps on asking otp?

is including FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD in env enough?
is there any other way?

Comment: See https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/#authentication-with-apple-services